# Multiple 2D contour plots in one 3D figure in python

Tags: python, 3d, contour

Is there any way available in python to plot multiple 2D contour plots in one 3D plot in python. I am currently using matplotlib for contouring, but not finding any option for what I am searching for. A sample image I have added. But I want to do it on Z-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig    = plt.figure()
ax     = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x      = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y   = np.meshgrid(x, x)
levels = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.4, 100)  #(z_min,z_max,number of contour),

a=0
b=1
c=2
Z1 = a+.1*np.sin(2*X)*np.sin(4*Y)
Z2 = b+.1*np.sin(3*X)*np.sin(4*Y)
Z3 = c+.1*np.sin(4*X)*np.sin(5*Y)

plt.contourf(X, Y,Z1, levels=a+levels,cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))
plt.contourf(X, Y,Z2, levels=b+levels,cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))
plt.contourf(X, Y,Z3, levels=c+levels,cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 2)

plt.show()
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Or, you can visit  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782821/clip-a-contourf-plot-in-3d-plot

Comment: This is essentially a 3D plot, not 2D contour plots stacked together.

Answer (score 1):

In order to plot true 2-D contour plots in one 3D plot, try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig    = plt.figure()
ax     = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x      = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y   = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z1 = .1*np.sin(2*X)*np.sin(4*Y)
Z2 = .1*np.sin(3*X)*np.sin(4*Y)
Z3 = .1*np.sin(4*X)*np.sin(5*Y)

levels=np.linspace(Z1.min(), Z1.max(), 100)
ax.contourf(X, Y,Z1, levels=levels, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

levels=np.linspace(Z2.min(), Z2.max(), 100)
ax.contourf(X, Y,Z2, levels=levels, zdir='z', offset=1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

levels=np.linspace(Z3.min(), Z3.max(), 100)
ax.contourf(X, Y,Z3, levels=levels, zdir='z', offset=2, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 2)

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOvKo.png)

Comment: Mind to explain your answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This sure did the work as explained in the official [website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/contourf3d_2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-contourf3d-2-py)