# Plotting 2D quiver plots in 3D as planes in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 2D plots, specifically quiver plots for this example, behind one another as if it was on a 3D axis. Attached is a picture of what I am trying to do: [Three quiver plots on the same axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaIL1.jpg)

I want to show the development as we move along the 'Z' axis (or 'X' axis in the attached picture), or in my case downstream.

I have researched ways to do this, but all I can find is ways to generate 3D plots, I do not find any way of making these 'planes' in three dimensional space. Using the 'zdir' argument as recommended by  [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html) did not deliver what I expected it to.

Additionally, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478681/multiple-2d-contour-plots-in-one-3d-figure-in-python), showed how to do this for contour plots, but I do not get it working for quiver plots.

Comment: are you going to plot a vector field evaluated from some analytical expression, or is a vector field coming out from some numerical simulation?

Comment: Maybe this helps : https://www.alphacodingskills.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-3d-quiver-plot.php

Comment: @Davide_sd - I will be plotting experimental data.

Comment: @HMH1013 - I managed to do a slight hybrid of that that worked: I inserted an array of zeros for the 'Z' velocity using np.zeros_like, and similarly added a constant location for the Z-location.

Comment: edit - added solution that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the syntax provided on https://www.alphacodingskills.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-3d-quiver-plot.php, the following managed to work, using data from a Pandas dataframe, data_x66 and data_x97 respectively. Numpy and Matplotlib were also used.

```
x = data_x66['X']
y = data_x66['Y']
z = np.zeros_like(x)
u = data_x66['VX']    
v = data_x66['VY']
w = np.zeros_like(u)

x2 = data_x97['X']
y2 = data_x97['Y']
z2 = np.zeros_like(x2)+10
u2 = data_x97['VX']
v2 = data_x97['VY']
w2 = np.zeros_like(u2)

ax = plt.figure('Full').add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(x,y,z,u,v,w,normalize=True)
ax.quiver(x2,y2,z2,u2,v2,w2,length=1,normalize=True)
```

[image: Solution]

[image: Different Angle]

It remains to make the plot look better.